# Is there a simple Javascript command that targets another object?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I have a page with two divs in it, one inside the other like so:

```
<div id='one'> 
<div id='two'></div>
</div>
```

I want div one to change class when it is clicked on, then change back when div two is selected.

I'm completely new to javascript, but I've managed to find a simple command that makes div one change when I click it.

```
<div id='one' class='a' onclick="this.className='b';">
<div id='two'></div>
</div>
```

Now I just need an equally simple way to change div one back when number two is clicked.

I've tried changing "this.className" to "one.classname," and for some reason that worked when I was working with images, but it doesn't work at all with divs

```
<div id='one' class='a' onclick="this.className='b';">
<div id='two' onclick="one.className='a';">
This does not work.
</div>
</div>
```

Essentially I'm wondering if there is a substitute for the javascript "this" that I can use to target other elements.

I've found several scripts that will perform the action I'm looking for, but I don't want to have to use a huge, long, complicated script if there is another simple one like the first I found.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Excellent first question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `document.getElementById`

```
<div id='two' onclick="document.getElementById('one').className='a'; return false;"> 
 This does not work. 
</div>
```

Comment: This continues to not work, but that's because it's still part of the other div and activates the other onclick at the same time. Once it's outside div one, it works beautifully. Thanks!

Comment: Notice that the divs are nested. The inner one will switch the outer to `a`, but then the event will bubble, and fire the handler on the outer, which will change it back to `b`.

Answer (score 3):

This would work:

```
document.getElementById('one').className = 'a';
```

Answer (score 0):

you could get the element by id with:

```
document.getElementById("one")
```